# Fully invariant subgroups of the group $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, invariance, characteristic-subgroups

I'm trying to find all fully invariant subgroups of the group $S_4$.
Meaning subgroups $H \leq S_4$, such that for all $\phi \in \operatorname{End}(S_4)$ the following holds: $\phi (H) \subseteq H$.

Of course the trivial subgroups $\{ e \} ,S_4$ are fully invariant, so I'm just interested in non-trivial subgroups.

I know that only characteristic subgroups (invariant under automorphisms) can be fully invariant. As $A_4, V_4$ are the only normal subgroups (invariant under inner automorphisms) these are the only possible subgroups that could be characteristic. That they are characteristic can be seen using the fact that being a characteristic subgroup is a transitive property and that automorphisms preserve order of elements. So $A_4$ must be characteristic in $S_4$, as it is generated by all elements of order $3$. By the same argument $V_4$ is characteristic in $A_4$, so in $S_4$.

Now I have to find out whether $A_4$ and $V_4$ are fully invariant. I'm missing arguments there, because I don't know many properties of endomorphisms on symmetric groups. Maybe someone has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: For $A_4$ you already have the answer, since the image of an element of order $3$ will have order either $1$ or $3$.

Comment: For the other one, note that if the endomorphism is not an automorphism, then it will have a non-trivial kernel. You already know what the possibilities for the kernel are.

Comment: The commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of any group $G$ is fully invariant, and $A_4 - [S_4,S_4]$.

Comment: Actually, scratch my previous comment. For the second one, use that it can be characterized nicely as a subgroup of $A_4$, which you already now know is fully invariant.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasKildetoft, I know understand why the $V_4$ is fully invariant. The kernel must be normal, so the only possibilities are $A_4$ and $V_4$. In both cases $V_4$ is in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution(just the comments above in one answer):
We know, both $A_4$ and $V_4$ are characteristic subgroups.
First I show, that $A_4$ is fully invariant. We know that the order of the image divides the order of the preimage. As $A_4$ is generated by all elements of order 3, the image of these generators must have order 3 or 1. In both cases it is in $A_4$.
For showing that $V_4$ is fully-invariant, we look at an endomorphism which is not an automorphism. It follows that the kernel is non-trivial, as it is normal it must be $S_4$, $A_4$, $V_4$. In all cases $V_4$ is contained in the kernel, though mapped to $e \in V_4$.